# How to name a method parameter with an identifier equaled ot Scala language keyword?

Tags: scala

So I tried to declare this simple case class

```
case class Association(id: Option[Long], type: String, name: String, description: Option[String], uri: URI, additonalInfo: String){

}
```

but it does not compile with this message:

```
- identifier expected but    'type' found.
```

It is of course because "type" is a reserved Scala keyword. I thought for some reasons that I can resolve this by providing a 'type (Symbol) instead but it still does not compile.

So how I can really label my parameter as a "type"?
Please do not disappoint me telling this cannot be done in Scala :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use thick quotes:

```
case class Association(id: Option[Long], `type`: String, name: String, description: Option[String], uri: URI, additonalInfo: String)
```

Comment: @AlexanderArendar: You can accept this answer to mark your question resolved.